# How to split index into new index and new column in Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with an index like "tt0000941-some text".  I would like to split the index at the first dash and make a new index containing the first part, e.g.  "tt0000941" and a new column containing everything after the first dash, e.g. "some text".

I have tried this:

```
df = df.rename_axis('idxTitle').reset_index()
df[['idx','title']] = df.idxTitle.str.split("-",expand=True)
```

The second command results in this error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 87002 entries, 0 to 87001
Data columns (total 29 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   idxTitle           87002 non-null  object 
 1   averageRating      87002 non-null  float64
 2   numVotes           87002 non-null  float64
 3   genre_Action       87002 non-null  float64
 4   genre_Adventure    87002 non-null  float64
 5   genre_Animation    87002 non-null  float64
 6   genre_Biography    87002 non-null  float64
 7   genre_Comedy       87002 non-null  float64
 8   genre_Crime        87002 non-null  float64
 9   genre_Documentary  87002 non-null  float64
 10  genre_Drama        87002 non-null  float64
 11  genre_Family       87002 non-null  float64
 12  genre_Fantasy      87002 non-null  float64
 13  genre_Film-Noir    87002 non-null  float64
 14  genre_History      87002 non-null  float64
 15  genre_Horror       87002 non-null  float64
 16  genre_Music        87002 non-null  float64
 17  genre_Musical      87002 non-null  float64
 18  genre_Mystery      87002 non-null  float64
 19  genre_News         87002 non-null  float64
 20  genre_Reality-TV   87002 non-null  float64
 21  genre_Romance      87002 non-null  float64
 22  genre_Sci-Fi       87002 non-null  float64
 23  genre_Short        87002 non-null  float64
 24  genre_Sport        87002 non-null  float64
 25  genre_Thriller     87002 non-null  float64
 26  genre_War          87002 non-null  float64
 27  genre_Western      87002 non-null  float64
 28  labels             87002 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(27), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 19.2+ MB
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have more then one `-` in your index

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'idxTitle': ['tt0000941-some text', 'tt0000941-some-text']
})
df[['idx','title']]  = df.idxTitle.str.split("-",expand=True)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

#### Fix: split only on first occurrence

```
df[['idx','title']]  = df.idxTitle.str.split("-",1, expand=True)
```

Output:

```
    idxTitle    idx title
0   tt0000941-some text tt0000941   some text
1   tt0000941-some-text tt0000941   some-text
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question.